# Is this function of 2 variables differentiable?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$f(x,y) = \frac{\sin(x^4+y^4)}{x^2+y^2}$ when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $0$ when  $(x,y) = (0,0)$

Is f differentiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote  $h=(h_x,\ h_y).$ Then the function increment is
$$\begin{align*}f(0+h_x,\ 0+h_y) - f(0,\ 0) = f(h_x,\ h_y) - 0 = \\
= \frac{\sin(h_x^4+h_y^4)}{h_x^2+h_y^2}  = 0 h+o\left(\|h\|\right),\;\;\; \|h\|=\sqrt{h_x^2+h_y^2} \to {0}, 
\end{align*}$$
therefore, $f$ is differentiable at $(0,\ 0)$ by the definition.